# If condition in matching strings(REGEX) in panda with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I just want to add a if condition before a regex matching:
first I define the regex and store the values in Name, then I print the Name value. The result is True and False(Boolean).

```
Name = df['Name'].str.match('^(\w+\s*)$')
#If the result matches True value passed and else the value will be False
print(Name)
```

Result

```
:
True
False
True
```

The below code is about the if condition I have. I don't know how to match if condition with a regex.
It seems the value of Name which is True/ False hasn't been checked in the if condition.

```
if Name is True:
     print(Name)
else:
     print('bye')
```

Code Result:

```
bye
```

Expected Result:

```
John
Saher
```

Thanks

Comment: You have not asked any questions, but judging by the story, you need `df.loc[Name,'Name']`.

Comment: Dear DYZ , I update my content. You are right and I appreciate the time you spend. I am new with python and panda. my question relates to if condition. Now where I have to add df.loc?

Comment: Just print it, and your text is still not a question.

Comment: My problem is about if condition not printing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df.loc[df['Name'].str.match(r'^\w+\s*$')]
```

Note you do not need the capturing group with a regex passed as an argument to `Series.str.match`, it is only required in `extract` / `extractall`.

If you want to allow any amount of leading whitespace chars, you may also add `\s*` after `^` and use `r'^\s*\w+\s*$'`.

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['John', '---', 'Saher']})
>>> df.loc[df['Name'].str.match('^(\w+\s*)$')]
    Name
0   John
2  Saher
```